# ObservableParcelable<String> is not working

Tags: android, android-databinding

In the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableParcelable.html) we see use of `ObservableParcelable` with `String` like this:

```
public final ObservableParcelable<String> name = new ObservableParcelable<String>();
```

But since `String` does not implement `Parcelable` there is no possibility of this being compiled. So how can I make my object extend `BaseObservable` and have observable fields and be parcelable at the same time?

Comment: why do you want to mix `BaseObservable` and `ObservableField` (and its siblings) ?

Comment: I have Object that extends BaseObservable and has ObservableField as fields. I want that object to be parcelable but observablefields aren't parcelable

Answer (score 0):

You can save not only parcelable fields, for example:

```
public class ViewModel extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable
{
    private ObservableField<String> title = new ObservableField<>();
    private ObservableInt count = new ObservableInt();

    private ViewModel(Parcel parcel)
    {
        title.set(parcel.readString());
        count.set(parcel.readInt());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags)
    {
        parcel.writeString(title.get());
        parcel.writeInt(count.get());
    }

    public static final Creator<ViewModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ViewModel>()
    {
        @Override
        public ViewModel createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new ViewModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ViewModel[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new ViewModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

But if you want to work with parcelable, that you should implement this interface for your classes

```
public class ParcelableString implements Parcelable
{
     private String value;

     /*Getter, Setter and implementation of Parcelable*/
}
```